# Display A list of Admins

Tags: author, list

I have a function that allows me to display ALL users on my site, but I was wondering if there was a way to display Admins and Contributors in a separate  loop?

My current function:

```
function contributors() {
  global $wpdb;

  $authors = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, user_nicename from $wpdb->users ORDER BY display_name");

  foreach($authors as $author) {
    echo "<li>";
    echo "<a href=\"".get_bloginfo('url')."/?author=";
    echo $author->ID;
    echo "\">";
    echo get_avatar($author->ID);
    echo "</a>";
    echo '<div>';
    echo "<a href=\"".get_bloginfo('url')."/?author=";
    echo $author->ID;
    echo "\">";
    the_author_meta('display_name', $author->ID);
    echo "</a>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</li>";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [get_users](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) function it allows you to query user by role.

For contributors,

```
 $contributors = get_users('role=contributors');
foreach($contributors as $contributors){
   // do something with contributors
}
```

For Admins,

```
$admins = get_users('role=admin');
   foreach($admins as $admins){
       // do something with admins
    }
```

replace role=* with your  desired roles.

Comment: Im currently using a variation of this and it seems to be doing the job. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`WP_User_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query) directly in your template files to display a list of users coupled to a specific role. As from the codex, here is a working example to display all admins

```
$args = array(
'role' => 'Administrator'
);

// The Query
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

// User Loop
if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
    foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {
        echo '<p>' . $user->display_name . '</p>';
    }
} else {
    echo 'No users found.';
}
```

You can do the same for 'Contributors'

Answer (score 0):

**Try this -**

```
$users = get_users('blog_id=1&orderby=display_name&role=administrator');
foreach ($users as $user) {
    echo '<li>' . $user->user_email . '</li>';
} 

$users = get_users('blog_id=1&orderby=display_name&role=contributor');
foreach ($users as $user) {
    echo '<li>' . $user->user_email . '</li>';
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to what your code does and how it works. Simply dumping code is not an answer